# Accessing variables from the aspx.cs class in my website! (ASP.NET Web Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My plan is to access waypoints from a database and show them in bing maps as a polyline.
The problem is the following: I have my default.aspx.cs class:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<Waypoints> waypointList;
    IWaypointLogic waypointLogic;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        waypointLogic = new WaypointLogic();
        waypointList = waypointLogic.GetWaypointsByTrackId(1);
    }
}
```

And now I want to access the waypointList in my default.aspx page. 
I want to do something like:

```
<% foreach (GPS_Tracker.Entities.Waypoints waypoint in waypointList %>
```

But I can't access the waypointList like this, can I?

Comment: You need  to make the variables in your code behind public or protected, then the form can access them.

Comment: make them `public` then you shall access.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it if you make it protected since the aspx markup generates a class that inherits your code behind. Also consider using some databound control if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Change the scope of your field to protected. e.g.

```
protected List<Waypoints> waypointList;
```

Answer (score 0):

try making your variables `public`.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<Waypoints> waypointList;//or protected
    public IWaypointLogic waypointLogic;//or protected

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        waypointLogic = new WaypointLogic();
        waypointList = waypointLogic.GetWaypointsByTrackId(1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:Also you can make them `protected` to access them, you can refer to George's comment on my answer for an explanation why you should use `protected` instead of `public`.

Comment: Since the page is a partial class, a public modifier may be a bit of overkill in this situation.

Comment: @George I didn't know about that George thanks, I will add that to my answer.